# Running external program asynchronously in C based on condition

Tags: c, process, exec, fork

I think I'm taking a good approach so far. In this code, I want it where a condition causes aflag to be set to either 1 or 2. Then based on the number, the respective program will be launched. so if aflag is 1, then `/path/to/app1` needs to be launched in the background and this program needs to continue. if aflag is 2 then `/path/to/app2` needs to be launched instead.

I could determine if the process is a child from `fork()` but I don't want to execute `fork()` in my main function since I don't want to execute a background process before it is time to start the program.

I'd also like to avoid using pthread and system functions if possible because I'm looking for the least resource intensive answer and people say `fork()` + `exec()` is the way to go.

How do I determine if the process at main is a child? and I want it to be able to know the program to run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

    static char *app1="/path/to/app1";
    static char *app2="/path/to/app2";
    static char *app;

    int otherfunction(){
      int aflag=0;
      //do something (will fill in later)
      if (aflag==1){
        //run app 1
        app=app1;
        fork();
      }
      if (aflag==2){
        //run app 2
        app=app2;
        fork();
      }

    }

int main(){
      int imachild=???;
      if (imachild==1){
        execl(app,NULL);
        return 0;
      }
      while(1){
      otherfunction();
      }
    }
```

Comment: "I don't want to execute fork() in my main function since I don't want to execute a background process before it is time to start the program.". Fine, call `fork` when you want to start the program. Then based on the return value either call `execl` (child) or don't call `execl` (parent).

Comment: So I can actually take the return value of fork to use in the child? How tho? I thought `fork()` starts the child and begins executing a copy of the `main()` function in my program before it returns a value.

Comment: @Mike, `fork` spawns off a child which *continues at the next statement*. It does not start in `main`. The difference is in that `fork` returns zero in the child, or the child's PID in the parent (or a negative value on error)

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code will give you some idea. Obviously this is just sample code with an infinete loop. Real code would likely have the parent accept input to set the `aflag` value. But it illustrates how the parent thread forks off a new process and how the new child process decides which application to run. And the parent process goes back to the next `fork` operation.

```
static char *app1="/path/to/app1";
static char *app2="/path/to/app2";

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int aflag = SOME_VALUE_OBTAINED_FROM_SOMEWHERE;
    const char *app = NULL;

    while (1) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid == -1) {
            printf("fork error\n");
        } else if (pid > 0) { 
            /* This is child code. */
            switch (aflag) {
            case 0:
                app = app1;        
                break;
            case 1:
                app = app2;
                break;
            }
            if (app) {
                execl(app, NULL);
                /* execl does not return on success */
                printf("execl error\n");
            } 
        } else {
            /*
             * This is the parent code - no exec. Just do 
             * something else.
             */
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: I'm trying to call `fork()` from outside of `main()`. Like I said. I don't want the forking to happen until I'm ready to execute an external program.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it is outside of main or inside. That is irrelevant in terms of actual runtime behaviour. That is just how you structure your code. The "else" condition in the above code (or actually before the fork) is where you would typically block and wait for an event that causes the parent to wake up, set `aflag` and do the `fork`.

Comment: You seem to be confused thinking that just because you put code into a function and call that function from `main` that somehow changes when the `fork` is called. It does not. It just changes the structure of your program (which is a good thing BTW).